# How to solve Cross-Origin-Request-Block issue while fetching data using angular2 and php?

Tags: php, angular, cors, angular2-services

Please read the question in detail since it is a long one with various edits and extended updates as per the request of other users.

I am trying to send data to php file using angular2. I am doing the angular project in Unix and the `var/www/html/` is the php Xampp folder locations for running the php files.

My folder structure is like this:-

```
var/www/html/
        |_(angproject)
                |_(phpscript)
                |       |_login.php
                |_(src)
                   |_(app)
                        |_(admin)
                        |   |_(login)
                        |   |   |_login.component.ts
                        |   |
                        |   |_admin.component.ts
                        |
                        |_(_admin_service)
                        |       |_admin.login.ts
                        |
                        |_(_animations)
                        |
                        |_(front)
                        |
                        |_(_models)
                        |   |_admin.model.ts
                        |
                        |_app.module.ts
```

My **app.module.ts** file is like this:-

```
import { HttpModule, Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { CanActivate } from "@angular/router";


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FrontComponent } from './front/front.component';
import { AdminComponent } from './admin/admin.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './admin/login/login.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './admin/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './admin/header/header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './admin/footer/footer.component';
import { LeftmenuComponent } from './admin/leftmenu/leftmenu.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './admin/navbar/navbar.component';
import { ShortcutbarComponent } from './admin/shortcutbar/shortcutbar.component';
import { AdminLoginService } from './_admin_service/admin.login';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'admin',
    component: AdminComponent,
    children: [
          { path: '', component: LoginComponent},
          { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent}
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    FrontComponent,
    AdminComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    LeftmenuComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    ShortcutbarComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    HttpModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes,
      { enableTracing: true } // <-- debugging purposes only
    )
  ],
  providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue : '/' },AdminLoginService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My **login.component.ts** file is this:-

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import { fadeInAnimation } from '../../_animations/index';
import { Admin } from '../../_models/admin.model';
import { AdminLoginService } from '../../_admin_service/admin.login';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
  animations: [fadeInAnimation],
  host: { '[@fadeInAnimation]': '' },
  providers: [AdminLoginService]
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    loading = false;
    returnUrl: string;
    responseStatus:Object= [];
    status:boolean ;
    //@Input() admin:Admin;

   model = new Admin('', '', '', 'Emailsss','Passwordsss'); 

    constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router,
        private _adminLogin: AdminLoginService
    ){}

  submitPost()
  {        
      //console.log("submit Post click happend " + this.model.email)
      //console.log(this.model);
      this._adminLogin.postLogin(this.model).subscribe(
         data => console.log(this.responseStatus = data),
         err => console.log(err),
         () => console.log('Request Completed')
      ); 
      this.status = true;       
  }

    ngOnInit() {

    }
}
```

The service file **admin.login.ts** file is this:-

```
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Admin } from '../_models/admin.model';

@Injectable()
export class AdminLoginService {
    http : Http;
    actionUrl : string;
    admin_login_Url: string;
    postData: Admin;


    constructor(public _http: Http) {
       this.http = _http;
       this.admin_login_Url = 'http://localhost/angproject/phpscript/login.php';
    }
    postLogin(postData:Admin) {
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
        headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","GET, POST");
        headers.append("Content-Type","application/json");

        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        console.log(postData);

        this.actionUrl = this.admin_login_Url;
        return this.http.post(this.actionUrl, {postData}, options)
          .map(res => res.json());          
    }
 }
```

And ultimately, my login.php file is this:-

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
include('connection.php');

$rawData    = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data       = json_decode($rawData, true);

$error = array();
if(isset($data['postData']['email']) && !empty($data['postData']['email']))
    $email = $data['postData']['email'];
else 
    $error[] = "Email was not entered";
if(isset($data['postData']['password']) && !empty($data['postData']['password']))
    $password = $data['postData']['password'];
else 
    $error[] = "Password was not entered";

if(empty($error))
{
    $runQuery = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$password'";
    $result = $conn->query($runQuery);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
    {
        $response['status'] = 1;
        $response['message'] = "Login successfully";
        $response['error'] = 0;
    } 
    else 
    {
        $response['status'] = 0;
        $response['message'] = "An error occured while logging in";
        $response['error'] = $conn->error;
    }
}
else
{
    $response['status'] = 0;
    $response['message'] = "Parameter missing";
    $response['error'] = $error;
}
$respond = json_encode($response);
echo $respond;
exit;
?>
```

Now here is the problem. When testing in Chrome, clicking the submit button once is firing calling for the php script (Ajax) twice. The first call doesn't send any data and hence it shows validation message in return response. The second call sends the form's data and hence fetching the desired result by matching the data sent.

[image]

In case of firefox, I am getting this response:-

[image]

[image]

How can I solve it?

**Note**:

Here are the Request Headers of the "**first call**" in chrome:

[image]
[image]

Here are the Request Headers of the "**second call**" in chrome:
[image]
[image]

**EDIT: Dated- 04-04-2018**:

As per the suggestions from **David**, I made subsequent changes in my login.php file:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS");
```

In the admin.login.ts file, I made the following changes:-

```
postLogin(postData:Admin) {
  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append("Accept", "q=0.8;application/json;q=0.9");
  this.actionUrl = this.admin_login_Url;
  return this.http.post(this.actionUrl, {postData}, { headers: headers })
          .map(res => res.json()).share();
    }
}
```

**Question 1:**
For the above code, I took reference from this [site](https://hassantariqblog.wordpress.com/2016/12/03/angular2-error-in-firefox-exception-syntaxerror-json-parse-unexpected-character-of-the-json-data/). Yet, I am still getting the error. How can I fix this in Firefox?

In the above code, I added the line `headers.append("Accept", "q=0.8;application/json;q=0.9");` to overcome an error shown below:-

[image]

How can I overcome this problem?

**Question 2:**

In Firefox, the console reads:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost/angproject/phpscript/register.php. (Reason: invalid token ‘application/x-www-form-urlencoded’ in CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’).
```

[image]

When checking in Chrome, I can see two calls in the network tab in console. The first call's request type is OPTIONS, while the second call has request type as POST.

In case of Firefox, I am getting only one call with request type OPTIONS. The POST request isn't taking place at all.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: there is a chrome plugin to fix it on local dev env

Comment: Would anybody care to explain why the downvote? It's not like I am begging for points, but I would appreciate if someone can explain the error in the question.

Comment: Can you show the response headers for the options request in your chrome debugger? And which webserver are you using

Comment: Sure. Give me some time to edit the question.

Comment: @David, I have added the request headers

Comment: These are the headers for the POST request, can you show the headers for the OPTIONS request? (the first one)

Comment: The Headers of the **OPTIONS requests** are also provided, just below the line `Here are the Request Headers of the "first call" in chrome:`

Comment: Sorry, I missed that: What if you try `header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");`

Comment: Same problem. Doens't solve my error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168097/discussion-between-david-and-saswat).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having 2 requests is normal, due to CORS implementation (client on `localhost:4200`, server on `localhost` = different ports).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Your problem is that you specified  some CORS headers in your request

```
headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","GET, POST");
headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
```

These headers are meant to be added server side, you don't need to send them from angular. They are actually causing the problem.

Remove them and it should work.

More information about **Access-Control-Allow-Headers**

`Access-Control-Allow-Headers` normally accepts a list of comma-separated headers.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers

The wildcard (*) value that you have on your PHP code is not supported on all browsers. On Firefox, the wildcard is not implemented yet 
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1309358

That's why firefox is bloking your POST, since the preflight (OPTIONS) request kind of fails

You don't need to specify `Content-Type` in your list since it's accepted by default

> The simple headers, Accept, Accept-Language, Content-Language, Content-Type (but only with a MIME type of its parsed value (ignoring parameters) of either application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain), are always available and don't need to be listed by this header.

**Edit**: actually, you do need to specify content-type in the list of accepted headers since you are sending `application/json`, which is not in the above list

Comment: The issue still exists in Firefox. Getting `EXCEPTION: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`

Comment: What did you try? Is it just for options request? Can you show response content

Comment: Check the question. I have made subsequent changes in the EDIT section.

Comment: Why do you add `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as a allowed header? It's not a header, it's a value !!! Besides, that's the value for the `Content-Type` header, which is NOT needed in the list as indicated above in yellow. Just remove your `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`, and add it if firefox still complains. IF you do, just add the list of header NAMES (not values)

Comment: Removing `header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");` causes error in Chrome, which gives message: `Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response`

Comment: Removing `header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");` causes error in Firefox which gives message: `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost/angproject/phpscript/login.php. (Reason: missing token ‘content-type’ in CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight channel).`

Comment: Add `header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type");` then

Comment: Yes, I edited my answer to add why you need to add that header :)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue while running the **angular app on chrome browser in windows**. Even I setup CORS configuration in a backend that issue didn't resolve. Then I realize that I need to disable the web security while running on a local machine or

> localhost/portNumber

Just hit the following command on cmd

```
TASKKILL /F /IM chrome.exe
start chrome.exe --args --disable-web-security –-allow-file-access-from-files
```

This resolved my problem :)